# im trying to plot a matplotlib graph but get an "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

im trying to plot a matplotlib graph but get an "TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable"

```
physical_sciences = np.array([13.8, 14.9, 14.8, 16.5, 18.2, 19.1, 20, 
                     21.3, 22.5, 23.7, 24.6, 25.7, 27.3, 27.6,
                     28, 27.5, 28.4, 30.4, 29.7, 31.3, 31.6, 
                     32.6, 32.6, 33.6, 34.8, 35.9, 37.3, 38.3,
                     39.7, 40.2, 41, 42.2, 41.1, 41.7, 42.1,
                     41.6, 40.8, 40.7, 40.7, 40.7, 40.2, 40.1])
computer_science = np.array([13.6, 13.6, 14.9, 16.4, 18.9, 19.8, 23.9, 25.7,
                    28.1, 30.2, 32.5, 34.8, 36.3, 37.1, 36.8, 35.7,
                    34.7, 32.4, 30.8, 29.9, 29.4, 28.7, 28.2, 28.5,
                    28.5, 27.5, 27.1, 26.8, 27, 28.1, 27.7, 27.6, 27,
                    25.1, 22.2, 20.6, 18.6, 17.6, 17.8, 18.1, 17.6, 18.2])
year = np.arange(1970, 2012)

plt.plot(physical_sciences)
plt.show();
```

Comment: You forgot to use `year` for the x-axis of your plot? I also don't think this is the error you getting from the code above. It should plot just fine. You should show a stacktrace.

Comment: This is not a complete runnable set of code so it’s hard to tell where you went wrong

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you have:

- *physical_sciences* - values for physical sciences,
- *computer_science* - values for computer science,
- *year* - values for *x* axis.

You can plot them e.g. as follows:

```
plt.plot(year, physical_sciences, 'bo', year, computer_science, 'go')
plt.show()
```

getting:

[image]

*plt.plot* takes triplets of parameters, passing:

- values for *x* axis,
- values for *y* axis,
- format.

See the documentation for format details.
You can choose other formatting of your choice.

In the above code you have 2 such triplets.

But a more elegant solution is to create a pandasonic *DataFrame*, with
explicit column names (will be used in the legend) and the index
from *year* (will be used as values for *x* axis).

Then you can generate the plot as:

```
df.plot();
```

getting:

[image]

Note the terminating semicolon in my code, so *plt.show()* is not needed.